# Same logic when comparing strings

Tags: php, mysql, encoding

In mysql, if you do this:

```
CREATE TABLE `foo` (`text` VARCHAR(36) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL) ENGINE = InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci;

INSERT INTO `foo` (`text`) VALUES ('Foo'), ('foo'), ('tel'), ('tél');

SELECT `text`, COUNT(*) AS `num` FROM `foo` GROUP BY `text`
```

you'll get this:

```
+------+-----+
| text | num |
+------+-----+
| Foo  |   2 |
| tel  |   2 |
+------+-----+
```

or:

```
SELECT * FROM `foo` WHERE `text` = 'tel';
```

results in:

```
+------+
| text |
+------+
| tel  |
| tél  |
+------+
```

Now, in php, is there a way to get something *similiar*?

E.g. checking for equality of `'tel'` and `'tél'` results in `true`?

Comment: what you mean and what you want ?  if('tel'=='tel'){ echo " true"; }else{ echo "false"; }

Comment: Well I would like to, in php, do a comparison of two input strings that behaves the same as with the mysql example above. Meaning `'tel'` is considered to be *the same* as `'tél'`.

Comment: if your input string tel present two times means the output would be tel=2 is it ?

Comment: The input is different, one is `tel` the other is `tél` (note the accent).

Comment: oh got it .@Ellie